# Cutting rectangular hole in a cylinder with subsurf modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I have a cylinder and I want to cut a  rectangular hole in it,I do it but when adding a subsurf modifier to the object and add some proximity loops but I fact this problem as you see here [image: the problem]

how can I fix this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to select the edges of you rectangle and increase the [*Crease Weight*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf) in the *Properties Panel*  <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

If this doesn't work well you could subdivide the cylinder before cutting, this way the influence of the *Subsurf Modifier* would be more local.

[image]