# Edge crease is making hard edges on curved surface

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make rectangle insets on a spherical shape, I have applied modifier to it. I apply edge crease so from having a circular inset its becomes like a rectangle shape, but its causing the outer parts to have a hard looking face. I tried adding loop cuts for support edges, but it distorts the shape.

[image]

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what crease is supposed to do. You have to crease just the inner edges to keep the rectangular shape, but I guess it creates bad artifacts when smoothing. So adding supporting edges will may be a better way.

Comment: I added only edge crease in the inner edges, but there seems to be a bit of pinching in the corners. https://ibb.co/tDqyC77

Comment: yep I thougth it would make something like that. There would be need of adding some supportive geometry to keep the hardsurface modeling clean as you wish. Here is a similar problem. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/cutting-rectangular-hole-in-a-cylinder-with-subsurf-modifier and here is another topology https://blenderartists.org/t/help-to-have-a-squared-hole-on-a-curved-surface/663545/8 you will have to make it more dense to reduce the bad effect

Comment: these links sure did help me get a better result. I mainly practice on low subdivided models, because sometimes people tell me its better to start off with less subdivision rather than a condensed model. But in this case more subdivisions worked well. Thanks.

Comment: Totally agree, its always better to work with low poly models. You can leave the part as it is and have in mind that it will be not visible in the final form. Or learn a topology that suits your model.